# Duplicate products to subdomain

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2

I can't find this anywhere so I'm going to assume it hasn't been asked.

Is there a way to duplicate my products from my primary site to my subdomain? It seems like it should have done it automatically but it hasn't.

Comment: By subdomain, do you mean a separate Craft 3 site in a multi-site install?

Comment: Correct Brad, I have the main site and then the subdomain. The suddomain is meant to have the same stuff as the main site, but the products don't show up. I found a way around this by resaving the products which forced them to copy over, but this apparently had issues and the site was suspended for problems in MySQL. I deleted the subdomain the multi-site, and now the site won't save products at all if I re-add the subdomain or make a new one.